# I have "apache reload" in my sudoers file along with NOPASSWD, but it still asks

Tags: apache2, sudo

I thought this was a pretty simple process. I want to basically reload apache (since I'll be adding/removing virtual hosts frequently), but I cannot seem to be able to get Apache to reload without it prompting me for my password.

Here's my `/etc/sudoers` file:

```
#
# This file MUST be edited with the 'visudo' command as root.
#
# Please consider adding local content in /etc/sudoers.d/ instead of
# directly modifying this file.
#
# See the man page for details on how to write a sudoers file.
#
Defaults    env_reset
Defaults    mail_badpass
Defaults    secure_path="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/snap/bin"

# Host alias specification

# User alias specification
subzero ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:/etc/init.d/apache2 reload

# Cmnd alias specification

# User privilege specification
root    ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL

# Members of the admin group may gain root privileges
%admin ALL=(ALL) ALL

# Allow members of group sudo to execute any command
%sudo   ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL

# See sudoers(5) for more information on "#include" directives:

#includedir /etc/sudoers.d
```

I've logged out and logged back in, and still no go. Any idea why this may not be working?

I also tried to move it towards the bottom just in case it was a priority thing, but still no luck.

Comment: Are you typing, exactly, `sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 reload`? Have you inspected `/var/log/auth.log*` and `/var/log/syslog*`?

Comment: Oh. I didn't realize I had to still type sudo. This makes sense and now this works. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you typing, exactly, `sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 reload`? You must.

Have you inspected `/var/log/auth.log*` and `/var/log/syslog*`? –